# Primefaces: Menu Button generate line break on chrome, but work fine on FF

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

If I have a menu button, and put some text after it, the text always get put onto the next line. I check the firebug and the only different between chrome and ff is this: 
This code generate in FF

```
//Code to generate the menu button
<script type="text/javascript">
   1widget_activate_j_idt21 = new PrimeFaces.widget.MenuButton('activate:j_idt21', {animated:'fade',zindex:1});
</script
```

[image: FF look]

This code generate in Chrome

```
//Code to generate the menu button
<script xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   widget_activate_j_idt21 = new PrimeFaces.widget.MenuButton('activate:j_idt21', {animated:'fade',zindex:1});
   //]]>
</script>
```

How can I eliminate this line break? (This line break is not caused because not having enough space for `.edu`)

[image: Chrome Look]

Comment: I'm not sure, but first shoot in the dark would be to give the element containing `.edu` a CSS `float:left;`.

Comment: @BalusC: I tried both float:right and float:left and it does not fix it. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
<f:view contentType="text/html">
```

to your page.